# How does setState work in the React function component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I wrote this code and I expect `A` to be 8 but it will be 6. Why?
If I deleted line 6 it would work correctly but if I did not use the callback in setState it would ignore all the lines above it.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
function SameSet() {
    const [A, setA] = useState(0)
    const go = () => {
        setA((preA) => preA + 1)
        setA(A + 1)
        setA((preA) => 2)
        setA((preA) => preA + 4)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {A}
            <button onClick={() => {
                go()
            }}> ok</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default SameSet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setA((preA) => 2)` defines a function, with a return value of `2`.
So `A` is set to 2.

The line after (last) adds another `2`, so `A` becomes `6` as shown here:

**Snippet:**

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const SameSet = () => {
    const [A, setA] = useState(0);
    const go = () => {
        setA((preA) => preA + 1)  // 0 + 1 = 1
        setA(A + 1)               // 1 + 1 = 2
        setA((preA) => 2)         // 2
        setA((preA) => preA + 4)  // 2 + 2 = 4
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {A}
            <button onClick={() => {
                go()
            }}> ok</button>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<SameSet />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

You'd probably always want to add `n` to the `prevA` like so to get the desired `8`:

```
setA((preA) => preA + 1);
setA((preA) => preA + 1);
setA((preA) => preA + 2);
setA((preA) => preA + 4);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const SameSet = () => {
    const [A, setA] = useState(0);
    const go = () => {
      setA((preA) => preA + 1);
      setA((preA) => preA + 1);
      setA((preA) => preA + 2);
      setA((preA) => preA + 4);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {A}
            <button onClick={() => {
                go()
            }}> ok</button>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<SameSet />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

These state updates are asynchronous. They might be sent in batches. There is no sure way of saying when the first three state updates will run. That is why it is always a **great** practice to use callback especially when you are using prev state value.(You are using the pattern here, but in different ways.)

```
setA((preA) => preA + 1) //Setting to 1 using previous Value
        setA(A + 1) //Setting to 1
        setA((preA) => 2) // Setting to 2 but not using previous Value
        setA((preA) => preA + 4) //Setting to 6 using previous Value
```

Line 6 is setting the value to a specific value which is being used later when using the callback pattern (prevValue). They will not be using the prev Value which  was say 0 at that time.

Comment: `setA(A+1)` is guaranteed to set `A` as 1, because `A` is still 0 at this point in the code.

Comment: Isn't there a possibility that the first state update would have triggered by then?

Comment: No. All this code in the handler is run synchronously and `A`, in this scope, is always whatever it was before the first `setA` is called. In the first `onClick`, that will be 0, so `0+1 = 1`. If you click it the second time, `A` will be 6 so `setA(A+1)` will **always** be 7.

Comment: `There is no sure way of saying when the first three lines will run`. This is incorrect, there is a sure way of saying when the first three lines run, they all run sychronously.

Answer (score 1):

`setA((preA) => 2)` simply returns 2 and sets `A` to `2`.
And thus following the next line `setA((preA) => preA + 4)` sets to `A` to `2 + 4 = 6`.
There can be a lot of problems like this. Just remember, `console.log()` is the greatest gift for all devs.